# from where http or https got selected in Magento 2

Tags: cookies, https, magento2

I Have to send all the unsecure request to secure one by making the site url as https in Magento as I am new to this and not able  to figure out how magento does this for frontend. Can Anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Login to Magento2 admin

Navigate to **Store--> Configuration --> Web**

There change the base URL with **HTTPS**.